# Memory management issues android

Tags: android, facebook, caching, memory, memory-management

I have 3 questions

> 1. How much does it effect android's memory when we call recyclerview.setadapter(new Adapter); instead of
>      notifydatasetchanged();
> 2. When using facebook app on android i see that obviously if we scroll down for a whole day the news feed of facebook will not end .
>      But facebook deosn't load all of its entire news feed at once . It
>      loads little by little as we scroll down . So my question is , i have
>      made an app in which i load questions asked by users in my
>      recyclerview . But as the time goes on the amount of questions
>      increase and i am still showing all of the questions at once which takes its
>      toll on the memory of the device and app starts to crash so how do i
>      load some questions and user scrolls down . I load next questions just
>      like facebook ?
> 3. Similar to the second question . How do i load only the questions i am showing on screen , in memory at a time?

P.S I am not including code because i thought there would be no need because i haven't done anything much different than a normal recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between setting a new Adapter in a `RecyclerView` and just calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` is substantial because when you call set new Adapter, the app will have to recreate all of its view holders and bind the ones needed all over again. The RecyclerView probably just did this and doing the work agian is unnecessary and tasking. Especially if this is called every time you receive new data, this will be a lot of work for your android app. The beauty of the `RecyclerView` is in its name. It reduces the amount of overload your app has by reusing (or recycling) views as they scroll off screen. Even if you have 10000 complex views, the app would still work pretty well because of the implementation of `RecyclerView`. All the views will never be in memory for long.

For your second question, you can check to see if a position in the `RecyclerView` is actually visible. If you check to see if the last item in your dataset is visible, then you can send a network request to gain more data. The way facebook probably does it. Other sites like Quora and Tumblr do the same in that when you reach the bottom of the feed it usually reloads and adds the new data to the dataset. If you want an even better experience, you can raise the threshold to not the last view, but some view before that so it never seems like feed stops and reloads. It can create an endless scrolling effect. The implementation is up to you, either way you will probably have to check the scrollstate of the `RecyclerView` and definitely call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or even better a variant of that.

The last question may already by taken care of by the `RecyclerView`. It depends on your data, but the `ViewHolders` should recycle in a way that you do not have many views in memory all at once.

Comment: thank u for the answer . Not 100% satisfied :p . But good answer :) . If i don't get a better answer i'll probably mark yours as expected , maybe :)

Comment: and btw when i use notifydatasetchanged instead of new adapter the memory increase is not alot , why is that?

Comment: @SyedMuhammadOan it depends on how much data you have. I was thinking in the range of complex views with lots of data (such as data with images and lots of text and many different components that the `RecyclerView` has to deal with). Overall, calling new adapter just seems inefficient when you have `notifydatasethchanged()`. Depending on your view and data, it may not be a huge increase, but even a slight one is damaging to your app. The amount of memory a device can have can be 2GB or less than 1GB. Either way, a lot of resources go  to Android resources and screen leaving little for your app

Comment: Can you accept this answer becuase there were no other answers. @SyedMuhammadOan